# Login block is missing from my theme

Tags: 6, blocks, users

The default login block is not listed in my theme's blocks, if I switch to Garland, it's there and if I type the direct path to the block I can access it, but I can't seem to save it to my block page... does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

1. Go to /admin/structure/block
2. Go to your theme (top tabs)
3. Move your login Block
4. WIN!

Comment: But the login block isn't listed anywhere on my theme block page, it's not in the disabled section or anywhere else.

Comment: are you on your admin theme or on your public website theme?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, I use Garland as my admin theme, but the block list displays in my custom theme...

Answer (score 0):

If your login block is missing from your blocks then

- from the **Structure->Blocks** view click on a **tab** that has another
  theme, different from your custom theme, preferrably Bartik or some
  other default theme.
- Now locate the user login block there and click configure.
- Set it to whatever region you want it to appear in your custom theme.
- Navigate back to your theme using the tabs in **Structure->Blocks**